# Heroku Git object enumeration is wrong, counting files that were already pushed

Tags: git, image, heroku, hosting, enumeration

I have an Heroku app and I use Git to push updates to it.
It hosts large amount of images, around 5500 simultaneously, changed occasionally.

In my last few pushes, I noticed the git objects enumeration is counting an exponential number of object from push to push. First 5500, then 11000, then 16500 and so on...

I'm sure the previous commits have been pushed, as I can see it on my Heroku apps.
I am also certain I haven't changed that many files in this commit.

It seems like Heroku pushes files to the app but maybe not to the remote Git client it uses. AFAIK, Heroku doesn't allow for remote git view so I can't be sure (fetching says eveything is usual) ***(EDIT: fetching now says the HEAD is on a lower commit. But files on app are updated! Something is broken?)***.

I need your help. I need some way to fix it so it will change only 5500 per push, otherwish pushes take FOREVER and usually gets a timeout from Heroku once writing is done.

If there isn't a solution, maybe an alternative way to upload files to Heroku, not via Git?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> If there isn't a solution, maybe an alternative way to upload files to
>   Heroku, not via Git?

Heroku Deploy buttons deploys your App to Heroku slightly differently. The git repository on Heroku still exists but if you clone it you'd see an empty repository.

You need an `app.json` and a Heroku Deploy Button, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#addons
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button

Reference examples:
https://github.com/vegeta897/d-zone/tree/heroku
https://github.com/dipu-bd/lightnovel-crawler
https://github.com/nntin/shell-kun
https://github.com/nntin/discord-twitter-bot

In case you are using git submodules they will not deploy correctly to Heroku, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#do-git-submodules-work

It will be deployed to Heroku through "repo-content tarballs". You aren't committing your whole git history to Heroku either.